# webdriver-user-agent gem classes not included in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, watir-webdriver

When I try to use the [webdriver-user-agent](https://github.com/alisterscott/webdriver-user-agent) gem, I cannot access the module, let alone its methods.

in Rails.root/Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    # ...
    watir-webdriver (0.6.10)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 2.18.0)
    webdriver-user-agent (7.1)
      facets
      json
      selenium-webdriver
    # ...
```

in Rails.root/app/models/some_model.rb:

```rb
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def some_function
    driver = WebDriver::UserAgent.driver(browser: :firefox, agent: :iphone, orientation: :portrait)
    # other functionality ...
  end
end
```

Load environment

```sh
rails c
```

Using the class:

```rb
2.0.0-p353 :001 > s = SomeModel.last
2.0.0-p353 :002 > s.some_function
NameError: uninitialized constant SomeModel::WebDriver
```

Is Rails looking for the Module in the wrong place by looking for it within SomeModel? Am I accessing this incorrectly? The module not is available:

```rb
2.0.0-p353 :003 > Webdriver::UserAgent
NameError: uninitialized constant WebDriver # corrected on edit
```

I've tried including `require 'webdriver-user-agent'` at the top of the class file, and then `include WebDriver` -- same error, but on loading of the model instance.

I filed [a bug report in the repo](https://github.com/alisterscott/webdriver-user-agent/issues/16), but I'm sure I'm doing something dumb here...

Additional info:

- Centos 6.5
- Rails 4.1.4
- Ruby 2.0
- Rubygems 2.2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to look for the module:

```
WebDriver
```

However, the webdriver-user-agent gem uses the module:

```
Webdriver
```

Notice the difference in the lowercase 'd'. Class and module names are case-sensitive, which is why the constant is not being found.

The function should work by correcting the module name:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def some_function
    driver = Webdriver::UserAgent.driver(browser: :firefox, agent: :iphone, orientation: :portrait)
    # other functionality ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I wish I could say 'I can't believe how dumb I was being', but I can believe it. Thank you, @justin-ko !

Comment: The naming convention used by Selenium is: "Selenium::WebDriver" (with a capital D), so I would actually suggest that at least part of the problem was the gem deciding to depart from convention by naming it a "Webdriver".